# Blurry sans serif font with T1 encoding

Tags: fonts

I am using T1 fontenc, and the sans serif font looks pixellated at high zoom. How can I solve this? If I load lmodern the problem is fixed, but then all other fonts change, which I do not really want.

I have problems only with the sans serif family, everything else is fine.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside, a4paper, onecolumn, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\large\sffamily\mdseries\upshape 

test
\end{document}
```

Output after pdflatex:

[image]

Comment: Which LaTeX installations and previewer? I get vector graphics when using your MWE via TeXLIve 2019.

Comment: I also get vector fonts using your MWE and recent MikTeX installation.

Comment: Do you have the cm-super package installed? You might use `\usepackage{lmodern}` in your preamble. The fonts look quite similar, but `lmodern` is a vector font and should work.

Comment: As an addition to Skillmons comment it seems you are using miktex (hence my question in the first comment), miktex uses bitmap fonts for the default fonts to save space. TeXLive is using cm-super as the default which is a scalable font (bitmap fonts aren't scalable)